# Exported Lossless Video - Output File Was Lossy

Tags: video-editor, video-quality, export

I recorded some video-game footage in 320x200 and then upscaled it to 1920x1440 using ffmpeg (nearest-neighbor, lossless libx264).

Screenshots of the upscaled footage have pixel-perfect color matching the original source.

However, when I import this footage into a video editor, and then immediately export it using a lossless format... color-banding occurs.

- Input Footage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/crGHF.png
- Output Footage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHbUy.png

I tried 3 different video editors (kdenlive, vsdc, shotcut). I tried five different lossless codecs (ffv1, h.264, huffyuv, utvideo, lossless jpeg). Nothing seems to work.

Any advice or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

---

**FFMPEG comparison between Input Source and VSDC Lossless JPEG Output (which gave best results, but not perfect...)**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i output.avi
ffmpeg version 4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 425 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), gbrp(tv, gbr/unknown/unknown), 1920x1440, 373 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 41 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, avi, from 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2019-08-17
    title           : input
    encoder         : msl
  Duration: 00:00:12.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 126738 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: jpegls (MJLS / 0x534C4A4D), rgb24(bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1440, lossless, 126664 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 1):

At least using Shotcut, you can get lossless output at minimum file size using the FFV1 codec.

1. In the export window, choose the `lossless/FFV1` preset.
2. Click the **Advanced** button at the bottom.
3. Go to the **Codec** tab, and set the **GOP** to `250` frames.
4. Go to the **Other** tab, delete everything there and type the following:

   ```
    coder=1
    context=1
    pix_fmt=bgr0
    mlt_image_format=rgb24
   ```

Source: https://forum.shotcut.org/t/lossless-annoyances/18344/2

---

### Edit (June 2021)

The newer versions of Shotcut have better options for lossless encoding with smaller output file size. Here are the steps:

1. Click the **Settings** menu > **Video Mode** > **Custom** > **Add...**, then set **Colorspace** to `BT.709` and click **OK**.
2. In the **Export** window, choose any preset and click the **Advanced** button at the bottom.
3. In the **Codec** tab, set **Codec** to `libx264rgb`, set **Rate control** to `Quality-based VBR`, set **Quality** to `100%`, and set **GOP** to `250`.
4. In the **Other** tab, delete everything and paste the following:

   ```
    pix_fmt=bgr24
    mlt_image_format=rgb24
    qp=0
   ```

When you're done you can save these settings for later use; click the **+** button at the bottom of the **Presets** list and choose a name for your custom preset.